# Captcha recaptcha does not work anymore

Tags: joomla2.5, recaptcha

It was working perfect yestarday but today the captcha does not appear anymore. I debuged the code and I realized that my joomla plugin captcharecaptcha is including this file when rendering the page as a javascript file

> http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js

But if I hit the link directly from my browser I get 404 not found. Anyone have any similar problems with this today? Did the path of the js file changed?

you can change the endpoints

From

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net";
const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

to

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

and it will work. I guess it will work with any version of joomla

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem but I changed it to

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js
```

and now it's working again. Hope this helps!

Comment: This gives me now: Warnung LG RECAPTCHA ERROR

Answer (score 18):

To fix this you need to change file /plugins/captcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.php

line 24

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net";
```

to

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api";
```

Google has change recaptcha code path and joomla hasn't still fixed this.

Comment: Well this was working yesterday and I was about to launch an application today. Unfortunately this drained all my time today and got me frustrated. I am done with this plugin. thank you.

Comment: At least they should have a warning or something some days before, or else it was my bad