# captcha-reCaptcha not showing in BT Login module

Tags: php, joomla, recaptcha

i am finally fed up of this problem, tried almost every solution but no solution.
I am using captcha-reCaptcha in my joomla website with BT login module, i can see the label captcha in the form but the captcha field is not showing, i am attaching the screenshot and recaptcha.php file as well where have changed the API SERVER URLs.

[image]

recaptcha.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Captcha
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.environment.browser');

/**
 * Recaptcha Plugin.
 * Based on the oficial recaptcha library( http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/ )
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Captcha
 * @since       2.5
 */
class plgCaptchaRecaptcha extends JPlugin
{
    const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
    const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
    const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "www.google.com";

    public function __construct($subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the captcha
     *
     * @param   string  $id The id of the field.
     *
     * @return  Boolean True on success, false otherwise
     *
     * @since  2.5
     */
    public function onInit($id)
    {
        // Initialise variables
        $lang       = $this->_getLanguage();
        $pubkey     = $this->params->get('public_key', '');
        $theme      = $this->params->get('theme', 'clean');

        if ($pubkey == null || $pubkey == '')
        {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_NO_PUBLIC_KEY'));
        }

        $server = self::RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER;
        if (JBrowser::getInstance()->isSSLConnection())
        {
            $server = self::RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER;
        }

        JHtml::_('script', $server.'/js/recaptcha_ajax.js');
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScriptDeclaration('window.addEvent(\'domready\', function() {
            Recaptcha.create("'.$pubkey.'", "dynamic_recaptcha_1", {theme: "'.$theme.'",'.$lang.'tabindex: 0});});'
        );

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the challenge HTML
     *
     * @return  string  The HTML to be embedded in the form.
     *
     * @since  2.5
     */
    public function onDisplay($name, $id, $class)
    {
        return '<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>';
    }

    /**
      * Calls an HTTP POST function to verify if the user's guess was correct
      *
      * @return  True if the answer is correct, false otherwise
      *
      * @since  2.5
      */
    public function onCheckAnswer($code)
    {
        // Initialise variables
        $privatekey = $this->params->get('private_key');
        $remoteip   = JRequest::getVar('REMOTE_ADDR', '', 'SERVER');
        $challenge  = JRequest::getString('recaptcha_challenge_field', '');
        $response   = JRequest::getString('recaptcha_response_field', '');;

        // Check for Private Key
        if (empty($privatekey))
        {
            $this->_subject->setError(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_NO_PRIVATE_KEY'));
            return false;
        }

        // Check for IP
        if (empty($remoteip))
        {
            $this->_subject->setError(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_NO_IP'));
            return false;
        }

        // Discard spam submissions
        if ($challenge == null || strlen($challenge) == 0 || $response == null || strlen($response) == 0)
        {
            $this->_subject->setError(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_EMPTY_SOLUTION'));
            return false;
        }

        $response = $this->_recaptcha_http_post(self::RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/verify",
                                                array(
                                                    'privatekey'    => $privatekey,
                                                    'remoteip'      => $remoteip,
                                                    'challenge'     => $challenge,
                                                    'response'      => $response
                                                )
                                          );

        $answers = explode("\n", $response[1]);

        if (trim($answers[0]) == 'true') {
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //@todo use exceptions here
            $this->_subject->setError(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', $answers[1]))));
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encodes the given data into a query string format.
     *
     * @param   string  $data  Array of string elements to be encoded
     *
     * @return  string  Encoded request
     *
     * @since  2.5
     */
    private function _recaptcha_qsencode($data)
    {
        $req = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }

        // Cut the last '&'
        $req = rtrim($req, '&');
        return $req;
    }

    /**
     * Submits an HTTP POST to a reCAPTCHA server.
     *
     * @param   string  $host
     * @param   string  $path
     * @param   array   $data
     * @param   int     $port
     *
     * @return  array   Response
     *
     * @since  2.5
     */
    private function _recaptcha_http_post($host, $path, $data, $port = 80)
    {
        $req = $this->_recaptcha_qsencode($data);

        $http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
        $http_request .= "User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP\r\n";
        $http_request .= "\r\n";
        $http_request .= $req;

        $response = '';
        if (($fs = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10)) == false )
        {
            die('Could not open socket');
        }

        fwrite($fs, $http_request);

        while (!feof($fs))
        {
            // One TCP-IP packet
            $response .= fgets($fs, 1160);
        }

        fclose($fs);
        $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get the language tag or a custom translation
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @since  2.5
     */
    private function _getLanguage()
    {
        // Initialise variables
        $language = JFactory::getLanguage();

        $tag = explode('-', $language->getTag());
        $tag = $tag[0];
        $available = array('en', 'pt', 'fr', 'de', 'nl', 'ru', 'es', 'tr');

        if (in_array($tag, $available))
        {
            return "lang : '" . $tag . "',";
        }

        // If the default language is not available, let's search for a custom translation
        if ($language->hasKey('PLG_RECAPTCHA_CUSTOM_LANG'))
        {
            $custom[] ='custom_translations : {';
            $custom[] ="\t".'instructions_visual : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_INSTRUCTIONS_VISUAL') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'instructions_audio : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_INSTRUCTIONS_AUDIO') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'play_again : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_PLAY_AGAIN') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'cant_hear_this : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_CANT_HEAR_THIS') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'visual_challenge : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_VISUAL_CHALLENGE') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'audio_challenge : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_AUDIO_CHALLENGE') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'refresh_btn : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_REFRESH_BTN') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'help_btn : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_HELP_BTN') . '",';
            $custom[] ="\t".'incorrect_try_again : "' . JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_INCORRECT_TRY_AGAIN') . '",';
            $custom[] ='},';
            $custom[] ="lang : '" . $tag . "',";

            return implode("\n", $custom);
        }

        // If nothing helps fall back to english
        return '';
    }
}
```

secondly there is no other login module enabled, no other captcha module is enabled.
Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Please try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841174/captcha-recaptcha-does-not-work-anymore

Comment: tried this a long ago, not working

Comment: I see.. Is your joomla version updated to the latest?

Comment: Please try to update as after 2.5.16 there is a correction to the captcha plugin.

Comment: can i update the version to latest that is 3.x.x ? or 2.5.16?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59163/discussion-between-rajesh-vishnani-and-emmanuel).

Comment: i did change, but there is no change in the result